# Can the multiverse theory be tested by gravity waves?

Tags: gravity, multiverse

I was wondering if the presence of multiverse could be detected by the fact that there is probably matter disturbing space-time that would cross boundaries?

Comment: Did you mean to ask about [gravitational waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) rather than [gravity waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

**If we don't detect gravity waves or we don't detect any "unexplained" gravity waves:**

That doesn't mean there aren't parallel universes leaking gravity.  It just means we didn't detect them (although it would help to constrain them).

Or it would simply mean that there are parallel universes but they can't leak gravity to us.

**If we do detect unexplained gravity waves:**

The possibility that the gravity waves are from our universe would be high.  We could never eliminate all possible sources (known and unknown) from our own universe to say confidently that the gravity waves were from a parallel universe.

There are definitely certain types of gravity waves we could detect that would point to a parallel universe as a likely source however if we don't detect these it doesn't mean that parallel universe isn't out there.

Comment: Based on what you're saying it seems like the answer then would be yes if we had the ability to isolate them.  With multiple synchronized detectors couldn't we isolate the origin and eliminate many knowns until the unknowns must be outside our universe?

Comment: If we completely surrounded an empty region with gravity wave detectors and determined the waves were coming from within the region that'd do a reasonable job of pointing to a multiverse.  That isn't a "test" of the multiverse theory though because negative detection proves nothing.

Comment: It basically comes down to falsifiability.  The various multiverse theories don't all predict gravity waves leaking into our universe.  A negative result does not falsify the theory even if gravity waves could possibly verify the theory.  Therefor gravitational waves are not a "test" of the theory.